# How to output the data with different lengths

Tags: r, statistics

R Version 2.11.1 32-bit on Windows 7

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this question. I got several arrays with different lengths, and I want put them together to output. For example:

```
a=c(1,2,3);
b=c(2,4,1,6)
c=c(4,5,9,2,8)
ra=rank(a);#ra=1 2 3
rb=rank(b);#rb=2 3 1 4
rc=rank(c);#rc=2 3 5 1 4
```

then how to put ra, rb and rc together to be this:

```
1 2 3

2 3 1 4

2 3 5 1 4
```

Yes, `list()` may be help, but how could I save it to my PC.
I tred to use `write.table()`, but fail.

Comment: You don't say what sort of output.  Is this to the display?  or to a file or what?  Do you want them output as string representations?

Comment: do you want to write() it as readable text or save() it as R objects?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik @user The best way to mark your question as 'solved' is to *accept an answer* by clicking on the green checkmark beside the answer that helped solve your problem, or, if you've found a solution yourself, answer your own question so that future readers know how you solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform list to matrix of strings.

```
a=c(1,2,3);
b=c(2,4,1,6)
c=c(4,5,9,2,8)

rlist <- lapply(list(a,b,c), rank)
m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(rlist, 
                           function(x) paste(x,collapse=" ")
                           )
             )
write.table(m,file="file_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `list`.

```
> list(ra, rb, rc)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 5 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> rlist <- lapply( list(a,b,c), rank)
> rlist
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 2 3 5 1 4
```